# How to delete scroll in grouping

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I use extJs 4.2.1 gridpanel with grouping feature in my form.

```
features: [
    {
        ftype: 'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: '<b>{[values.children[0].data.typeName]}</b>',
        hideGroupedHeader: false,
        collapsible : false,
        startCollapsed: false,
        id: 'directorInfoGroupping'
    }
],
```

I have scroll(look at image) in buttom of my gridpanel, how I can delete or hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find gridpanel property 'scroll':

```
scroll : String/Boolean
Scrollers configuration. Valid values are 'both', 'horizontal' or 'vertical'. True implies 'both'. False implies 'none'.
```

It helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

You want add the following property

```
autoScroll :false
```

For more details see here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-autoScroll

Comment: I already have autoScroll :false in my gridpanel, so it's not helped me.